How to store field content contained in a dynamic form created by javascript?
I have this html + ajax code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Compila Preventivo</title>
    <style>
        /* Stile CSS predefinito */
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .container {
            max-width: 800px;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        .section {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #fafafa;
        }
        .form-row {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .form-row label {
            flex: 1;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .form-row input, .form-row select, .form-row textarea {
            flex: 2;
        }
        .add-row-btn {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .remove-row-btn {
            background-color: #e74c3c;
            color: white;
            padding: 5px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Compila Preventivo</h1>
    
    <form action="salva_preventivo.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="section">
            <h2>Dati Intestazione Preventivo</h2>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="numprev">Numero Preventivo:</label>
                <input type="text" id="numprev" name="numprev" value="<?php echo $numprev; ?>" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="tipo_preventivo">Tipo Preventivo:</label>
                <input type="text" id="tipo_preventivo" name="tipo_preventivo" value="<?php echo $tipo_preventivo; ?>" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section">
            <h2>Aggiungi Righe Preventivo</h2>

            <div id="righe-container">
                <!-- Prima riga precompilata -->
                <div class="riga" data-numriga="1">
                    <h3>Riga 1</h3>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="numriga_1">Numero Riga:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="numriga_1" name="numriga[]" value="1" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="tiporiga_1">Tipo Riga:</label>
                        <select id="tiporiga_1" name="tiporiga[]">
                            <option value="paragrafo">Paragrafo</option>
                            <option value="descrizione">Descrizione</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="immagine_1">Immagine:</label>
                        <input type="file" id="immagine_1" name="immagine[]">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="descrizione_1">Descrizione:</label>
                        <textarea id="descrizione_1" name="descrizione[]" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="prezzo_1">Prezzo (€):</label>
                        <input type="number" step="0.01" id="prezzo_1" name="prezzo[]">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="remove-row-btn" onclick="rimuoviRiga(this)">Rimuovi Riga</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="button" class="add-row-btn" onclick="aggiungiRiga()">Aggiungi Riga</button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <button type="submit" name="salva" value="Salva" class="add-row-btn">Salva Preventivo</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    let numRiga = 1;

    // Funzione per aggiungere una nuova riga
    function aggiungiRiga() {
        numRiga++;
        const righeContainer = document.getElementById('righe-container');
        
        const nuovaRiga = document.createElement('div');
        nuovaRiga.classList.add('riga');
        nuovaRiga.setAttribute('data-numriga', numRiga);

        nuovaRiga.innerHTML = `
            <h3>Riga ${numRiga}</h3>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="numriga_${numRiga}">Numero Riga:</label>
                <input type="text" id="numriga_${numRiga}" name="numriga[]" value="${numRiga}" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="tiporiga_${numRiga}">Tipo Riga:</label>
                <select id="tiporiga_${numRiga}" name="tiporiga[]">
                    <option value="paragrafo">Paragrafo</option>
                    <option value="descrizione">Descrizione</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="immagine_${numRiga}">Immagine:</label>
                <input type="file" id="immagine_${numRiga}" name="immagine[]">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="descrizione_${numRiga}">Descrizione:</label>
                <textarea id="descrizione_${numRiga}" name="descrizione[]" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="prezzo_${numRiga}">Prezzo (€):</label>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" id="prezzo_${numRiga}" name="prezzo[]">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="remove-row-btn" onclick="rimuoviRiga(this)">Rimuovi Riga</button>
        `;
        
        righeContainer.appendChild(nuovaRiga);
    }

    // Funzione per rimuovere una riga
    function rimuoviRiga(button) {
        const riga = button.closest('.riga');
        riga.remove();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>

and I want define a Php code to save on a table on a DB  that is this. In particular i want that as many row where added to the form as many row where added in the following table. Exist a simple way to do that?
CREATE TABLE Righe (
    idriga INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    numprev VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    numriga INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    tiporiga ENUM('paragrafo', 'descrizione') NOT NULL,
    immagine MEDIUMBLOB,
    descrizione TEXT NOT NULL,
    prezzo DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (numprev) REFERENCES Oggetto (numprev)
);

Sorry i have no idea how to do that, probably i need to use a framework like laravell?
please tell me how can i store dynamic input field values in database using PHP.

There is no AJAX code in your sample, just some regular JavaScript to add new rows to your form. When you submit the form, all the rows inside it will be submitted to the server together. You can use standard PHP code to read the form values from the $_POST array, and then add them as parameters to a SQL INSERT query so that you save them to the database. (You should consider using a loop to process each submitted row of data and insert it.). You don't really need to use AJAX for this if you don't want to add that complexity. You also don't need a PHP framework if you don't want to.

Handling form data and inserting rows into a database must be the topic of 1001 PHP tutorials online. Where exactly are you stuck with this task? Have you researched or tried anything yet?

@Barmar the names look fine to me. It's only the IDs which are done like that.

Oh, read too quickly. They probably don't even need the IDs. Instead of using <label for=XXX>, wrap the label around the input: <label>XXX:<input></label>
